# Treeview Binding (With a 'Folder' between the bound Nodes)

Tags: wpf, data-binding, tree, treeview, itemssource

I have following problem with which I'm wrestling now for about 5 hours.

How do I correctly bind the following class structure to a TreeView?

```
public class Person
{
    public string Display { get; set; }
    public List<Car> Cars { get; set; }
    public List<House> Houses { get; set; }
}

public class Car
{
    public string Display { get; set; }
}

public class House
{
    public string Display { get; set; }
}
```

I want the TreeView to have the following structure:
(Where Person #1 has both houses and cars, and Person #2 just has houses)

```
- Person #1
|-- Cars
  |-- Car #1
  |-- Car #2
|-- Houses
  |-- House #1
- Person #2
|-- Houses
  |-- House #1
  |-- House #2
```

How on earth do you this in XAML with automatic Databinding to an ObservableCollection?
I set the binding only once in the Constructor of my Treeview (UserControl) like this:

```
this.ItemsSource = SomeStaticClass.People;
```

Help is very very much appreciated!
Thanks! =)

EDIT:
I tried the HierarchicalDataTemplate, but I can't get it to work ;)

EDIT2: I tried many many different things, but the closest I have come to is following code (with just one Enumeration in mind at this time ;)):

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type e:Person}" ItemsSource="{Binding Cars}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Display}" />
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Cars}">
            <TextBlock Text="Cars" />
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Display}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't display the TextBlock Cars and the Cars themself. How do I do that?

Comment: have you tried [`HierarchicalDataTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate.aspx)?

Comment: Yes, I have tried everything with this template. It won't work, it doesn't matter what I try. :)

Comment: See Edit2 For my editet answer which shows my code so far. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved.
I just inserted another Collection of classes between my Person and Car (resp. Home) like this:

```
public class CollectionHolder<T> : IEnumerable
{
    public List<T> Items { get; set; }
    public string Display { get; set; }

    private List<CollectionHolder<T>> self;
    public CollectionHolder()
    {
        self = new List<CollectionHolder<T>>();
        self.add(this);
    }

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return self.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

And than the Person class:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Display { get; set; }
    public CollectionHolder<Car> Cars { get; set; }
    public CollectionHolder<House> Houses { get; set; }

    public IList Children
    {
        get
        {
            return new CompositeCollection
                {
                    new CollectionContainer { Collection = Cars },
                    new CollectionContainer { Collection = Houses }
                });//In real world: don't generate the list everytime!
        }
    }
}
```

And finally my XAML:

```
    <TreeView x:Name="trvData" Grid.Row="0" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1">
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type e:Person}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Display}" />
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Display}" />
                        <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Display}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.Resources>
    </TreeView>
```

Comment: I will tomorrow, 'cos the waiting time (maybe just for low-pointers like me) for marking your own answer as the correct one is one day.

Comment: Do you really need a composite collection there? Usually you would use that to aggregate collections without anything between them (like your `Cars` or `Houses` folders)

Comment: I really don't know if I need it there, but I got it working this way. If you have another solution to my problem, I'd be more than happy to here it. :)